# SAS PROC SQL - How to convert string to number

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I want to convert a string to number in a SAS SQL PROC.
The oracle-sql functioncs as `TO_NUMBER()` or `INT()` do not work.
I also tried the `CAST(<my string> AS <target type>)` function but it does not recognize the target type INT or INTEGER.

Comment: Have you tried "input"?

Comment: Not yet, I just discoverd which is the sql language used in SAS SQL PROC
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51981079/sas-what-is-the-sql-language-used-in-a-proc-sql

Comment: You have a string st = "1234" ==> convert it to number : input(st, 4.). 4. is the size of the number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the best way would be to use:

```
input(your_string_variable, best.) as your_new_numeric_variable
```

You need to replace your_string_variable and your_new_numeric_variable appropriately. Best. is SAS format ("informat", to be exact) that tries to read in as many reasonable numeric formats as possible, it will work in majority of cases whether representation of a number you have. Still it makes sense to review the results or find a more specific format if you're interested in controlling the input.

Comment: Can you specify how to use the parameter _best._?