# SAS - What is the SQL language used in a PROC SQL?

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I'm new to SAS and I'm using the PROC SQL functionality.
I can not understand which is the sql language used in the PROC SQL.

It seems similar to Oracle-Sql but some functions are not available.

Can anyone clarify this point?

Comment: PROC SQL is the SAS implementation of SQL. Different providers have their own implementation. this does not necessarily have to be the same. Only the default functionality set defined in SQL standard may be the same.

Comment: [It seems to be their own dialect](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/63043/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0corah7t43hy7n1r7efplde5c8z.htm); resemblance to Oracle or any other flavour is expected through the standards, which they all adhere to to varying degrees.

Comment: Syntactically it is more or less vanilla; functions may differ.  If you are an "experienced" SQL user: dont expect "complex" queries to perform, SAS does not have enough catalog data to generate smart query plans (eg anti-joins using indexes, junction tables, ...) SAS doesn't support any datatypes except for character and float, so even integers can be cumbersome. Dates are a pain. PROC SQL can be handy for querying *the catalogs*, avoiding ugly macros...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PROC SQL supports the ANSI SQL definition from 1992.  You can also use most SAS functions.

> International Organization for Standardization (ISO): Database SQL.
>   Document ISO/IEC 9075:1992. Also, as American National Standards
>   Institute (ANSI) Document ANSI X3.135-1992

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/63043/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0corah7t43hy7n1r7efplde5c8z.htm